# Array error - Invalid argument - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

My variable $x holds:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (5) { 
     ["polarity"]=> string(7) "neutral"
     ["subjectivity"]=> string(9) "objective" ["text"]=> string(0) ""
     ["polarity_confidence"]=> float(0.77262067409886)
     ["subjectivity_confidence"]=> float(0.54271560213894) 
}
```

The above is the output of $x from a var_dump.

I am trying to get the polarity value ("neutral").

I tried the following but got Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
foreach($x->polarity as $polarity) {

    $value = $x->polarity[0];
    var_dump ($value);
}
```

Comment: Simply use `$x->polarity`, no need to use for loop

Comment: yes, no need loop direct use 'echo $x->polarity'

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above,

```
  $x->polarity;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
foreach($x as $key => $value) {
    print "$key => $value\n";
}
echo "\n";
```

Comment: Creating a new instance of the class polarity in case it needs to be instantiated

Comment: It is an object ,so assuming it is an instance of a class

Comment: There is no need to convert a object to an array before looping. You can check in http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593) [The same goes for incorrect answers.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/2747593)